# How to draw a square around the points in the image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I have a binary image, with white points. How can I identify and draw a square around these points using OpenCV?

The problem is that the points are very small, and so far all the attempts have failed to find all the points.

This is the input image:
[image: bin image]

This is the result I am interested in:
[image: exepted result]

Is there a possibility using a function of OpenCV?
And if not, (because of size), what is the most effective way?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Are all pixels that aren't points black, and are all pixels that are parts of points white? Also, how close do two points need to be to be grouped in a single yellow box?

Comment: take a look at this: https://www.learnopencv.com/how-to-select-a-bounding-box-roi-in-opencv-cpp-python/

Comment: How can I tell how many points should be in each square? Some of your squares contain 1 point, some contain 4, some 5.

Comment: Thank you.
I want to surround only the white pixels.
And I want all the points in the area to be at most 10 pixels, they will be considered one area.

Comment: So you are interested in finding clustered white dots rather than singlurar coherent dots?

Comment: It is true that I want to find white points, and to consider points that are actually adjacent to a part of that area.

Answer (score 1):

Using following method you can find a solution.

Full code for the solution:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
img = cv2.imread('test.jpg', 0)
output_img = img.copy()
cv2.threshold(img,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU,img)

kernel = np.ones((50,70), np.uint8)
img = cv2.dilate(img, kernel, iterations=1)


im2,contours, hier = cv2.findContours(img.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
for c in contours:
    # get the bounding rect
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
    # draw a white rectangle to visualize the bounding rect
    cv2.rectangle(output_img, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), 255, 1)

cv2.imshow('output',output_img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

- First you have to create a kernel according to your requirement.
- Bigger the kernel size, points belong to a cluster will be higher.
- Then using `cv2.dilate` method you should dilate the image using
  created kernel.
- After that you should find contours of dilated image and get the
  bounding rectangle of those contours.
- One rectangle can be considered as one cluster.
  You can change the cluster size using `kernel = np.ones((50,70), np.uint8)` In here it is 50 x 70.

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Apply [dilate](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/erosion_dilatation/erosion_dilatation.html) on your image with size 5.
2. If distance of between dots < 10, they will be joined to one big
   dot.
3. If distance > 10, it will be seperated as it is.
4. [Find contours](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/find_contours/find_contours.html) on result.
5. Get [minAreaRect](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga3d476a3417130ae5154aea421ca7ead9) of each contours.
6. Done.